# Examples on Literate Programming with Racket scribble/lp

Tags: racket, literate-programming, scribble

In addition to learning Racket I'm trying to learn literate programming. Unfortunately the Racket documentation is sparse to say the least with regards to scribble/lp. Could someone point me to some better resources on this subject or examples of literate programs written in Racket?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small puzzle game in Racket, using the `scribble/lp` library: https://github.com/racket/games/blob/master/chat-noir/chat-noir-literate.rkt

Answer (score 3):

Here is another shorter and self - explanatory example:

[Project Repository Github.](https://github.com/brudgers/LiterateProgrammingExample)

[Project Page using woven output.](http://brudgers.github.io/LiterateProgrammingExample/)

It was written to cover some of the gaps in the Racket documentation.